# Why is there a margin of the body and not the container?

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time figuring out why is the margin set on my nav element is being pushed down from the body and not from the parent element the container. In the code below I have a grey background, and white container. When I apply a top margin in my nav the white container gets pushed down and not my nav.

If anyone can help me understand this, I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

```css
html,body{
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    background-color: white;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
nav{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <nav>
            <span>Nav 1</span>
            <span>Nav 2</span>
            <span>Nav 3</span>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because **margins collapse**. Similarly borders and padding too. To avoid this collapse you can use one of the following solution:

**Solution : 1**

**Add `overflow: auto;` OR `overflow: hidden;` to the `container` class.**

**Plnkr DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/9kpcNulpRYyRkUd3HFuJ?p=preview

**Stack Snippet:**

```css
html,body{
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.container{    
    background-color: white;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; /* overflow */
}

nav{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class='container'>
        <nav>
            <span>Nav 1</span>
            <span>Nav 2</span>
            <span>Nav 3</span>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Solution : 2**

**Use Margin and Padding Reset:**

```css
html,body{
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.container{    
    background-color: white;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 1px; /* padding and margin resets */
    margin-top: -1px;
}

nav{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class='container'>
        <nav>
            <span>Nav 1</span>
            <span>Nav 2</span>
            <span>Nav 3</span>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your margin is not pushed down from the body but from the from the container with class `.container`

In the snippet below

The div with class `container` has border blue and the `nav` has border `red`

the nav is still in the div which is in the body

**Snippet**

```html
<style>
  html,
  body {
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    background-color: white;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border: solid blue;
  }
  nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: solid red;
    position: relative;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <nav>
      <span>Nav 1</span>
      <span>Nav 2</span>
      <span>Nav 3</span>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works **only** because you added a border to the container. It will not work without the border.

Comment: A css border property does not affect how a margin works....it is a style

Comment: [container with border](https://jsfiddle.net/7z7pe3kp/) vs [container without border](https://jsfiddle.net/7z7pe3kp/1/) - checked on both chrome & firefox

Comment: Interesting..however if you use firefox inspect element tool you will see it highlights the nav container and also show yellow section above the nav container which is the margin hidden above the nav.....it appears that styling with border will actually show that the margin is in the container and not hidden

Answer (score 0):

Probably your border is not defined Try defining the border of the container make it `sth` like

```
.container { border-style: solid;
 color: White;
 width: (your preferred width);
 height: (your preferred height );
 }
```

Try it and let me know if it worked. Also before you start your `stylesheets` it is advisable to use `css` resets.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because sometimes the css rules are just dumb.
Here is a fix.

add this class in the css after your .container class:

```
 .container::before {
           clear: both;
           content: "";
           display:table;
        }
```

That should fix the problem. Have a look https://jsfiddle.net/e4k6L2nr/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of people like to start off their style sheet with a css normalizer which I don't believe was explicitly covered here. I got turned onto it while doing some wordpress theme development using underscores.

```
* {
    margin:0;
}
```

That's basically all you need. It helps overwrite predefined styles users may have attached to their browsers or other rules you didn't know you set up.

Let me add, the * selector, selects everything. Sometimes I'll also use that area to remove text-decoration and establish a base font-size so I can use em or rem later.

Answer (score 0):

From the tests I've done, it seems that the margin property is applied to the parent when the element is the first of the division.

I would encourage you to use the padding property instead.
You can find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) some information on the differences between these properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
   

        html,body{
            background-color: lightgray;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .container{
            background-color: white;
            width: 600px;
            margin: auto;
            height: 100%;
        }

        nav{
            position: relative;
            top: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>


<div class='container'>
    <nav>
        <span>Nav 1</span>
        <span>Nav 2</span>
        <span>Nav 3</span>
    </nav>
   </div>

</body>
  </html>
```